# back button does not reload landing page after form submission

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form on a web page (call it PAGE A) where the user needs to press a button to determine wether or not to move to the next page (call it PAGE B). If the user accepts, the form is submitted and a new page (PAGE B) is called along with some variables passed through GET method.

On the new page (PAGE B) there are some divs with hyperlinks. If I press on one of them I open a new page (call it PAGE C). When I press the back button, PAGE B is called but no content is displayed. How to reload the full PAGE B? I believe the problem is that the variables passed through the GET method are not resent when I press the back button from PAGE C?

This is page A

```
<?php
$back="pageB.php?var1=aa&var2=bb";
?>
<div align="center">
    <br><br><br>
    Attenzione! <br><br>
    Per visualizzare gli annunci e' necessario usare uno degli accessi residui del
    proprio abbonamento.<br><br>
    Attualmente hai a disposizione 6 accessi. Vuoi continuare?
    <br><br><br>
    <form action="<?php echo $back; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="_self">  
        <input type="hidden" name="ipay" value="1">
        <input type="submit" value="Si accetto">
    </form>
    <br><br><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Your method is `POST` not `GET`. In normal cases, browser should ask you if you would like to resend the form. If it doesn't, you need to save the values in `$_SESSION` and populate them again.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The browser does ask to resend the form but that is what I want to avoid. How to do that? Thanks

Comment: If you would like it to not to ask, you should use sessions to store the posted data, and `header('location: ...'`) to redirect it to another page (can be the same) right after getting it, that would fill the data from session.